# TableView with little less performance

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'll try to implement a TableView with 2 different kinds of cells, the first one is a higher Cell with a fullwidth image inside, all other cells got a little thumb image on the left side.

My problem it the performance of the TableView. If I scroll a list of maybe 20 items it jerks a bit. I've red something the performance and I'll hope the code is not so bad:

1. "Caching of images is not necessary to raise the performance" Is this right?
2. Does I reuse the cells in the right way.
3. Is that the normal way to use 2 different kinds of Cells?

Here is the important Part:

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        return 160;
    }
    return 60;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *cellName = [[NSString alloc] init];

    // [...]

    if(indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0){
        cellName = @"FirstMainCell";
        CellTemplateFirstNews *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellName];
        if(cell == nil){
            cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellTemplateFirstNewsView" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        NSURL *urlRowImage = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://webserver.de/inhalte/news/title/%@", detailDataNews.title_picture]];
        NSData *dataRowImage = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlRowImage];
        UIImageView *firstNewsImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 160)];
        firstNewsImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        firstNewsImageView.opaque = NO;
        firstNewsImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:dataRowImage];
        cell.backgroundView = firstNewsImageView;

        // [...]

        return cell;
    }else{
        cellName = @"MainCell";
        CellTemplateNews *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellName];
        if(cell == nil){
            cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellTemplateNewsView" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        NSURL *urlRowImage = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://webserver.de/inhalte/news/cover/%@", detailDataNews.cover_picture]];
        NSData *dataRowImage = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlRowImage];
        UIImage *rowImage = [UIImage imageWithData:dataRowImage];
        cell.thumbImage.image = rowImage;

        // [...]

        return cell;
    }
}r
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem is the synchronous network request that's happening for every cell, whether it's reused or not.  The culprit is `dataWithContentsOfURL:`.

Check out this [apple sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html), or google the phrase "ios lazy table images".  [In this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655360/images-downloaded-asynchronously-only-appear-in-uitableview-after-tap-or-scroll/12656334#12656334), I provide a fairly simple to implement method that takes care of the loading an image asynch, then finding and updating the correct table view row upon completion.

Comment: Thanks. Now i use the LazyTable sample and the scrolling works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do not alloc-init any object in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` You are probably leaking massive memory. Remember, this method called every time a cell comes into view, even cells that have been previously shown.

Also, your assignments to string variables are redundant. It is sufficient to do it like this.

```
BOOL firstCell = (indexPath.row==0 && indexPath.section==0);
NSString *cellIdentifier = firstCell ? @"FirstMainCell" : @"MainCell"; 
UITableViewCell *genericCell = [tableView 
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (firstCell) {
   cell = (CellTemplateFirstNews*) genericCell;
   // configure...
} 

else {
   cell = (CellTemplateNews*) genericCell;
   // configure...
}

return cell;
```

The other possible reason for your lag is the synchronous call to the web service. You are doing this each time the cell becomes visible. You need to load the images lazily and update the UI when necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i think misunderstood this part. I 'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: It's fine to alloc init inside of the if(cell == nil) block, as long as you're reusing cells.

Comment: agree with your point about string alloc/init, but it's just an empty string.  i think the bigger problem is initializing images from the web, synchronously, every time.

Comment: I 'll tried this to get a cleaner code, but the changing of the celltype doesn't work. After 'cell = (CellTemplateFirstNews*) cell;' i cant access the attributes of CellTemplateFirstNews.

Comment: Strange. Try calling the original cell `genericCell` and then `CellTemplateFirstNews *cell = (CellTemplateFirstNews*) genericCell;`.

Answer (score 0):

One posibility is that you've forgotten to enter the `CellIdentifier` in your Xib. In fact the reuseIdentifier method needs your cell to have the same identifier, but you never set it when you create your cell. Those cells in your Xib have to have their identifier entered.