# Refactoring uitableviewcell async image loading

Tags: ios, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

So i have problem...For me, Having the dispatch_async code within cellForRowAtIndexPath method is too clunky and messy for me.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myCellID";
    myCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // someData - an array of dictionary for the tableview datasource
    NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:someData[indexPath.row][@"photoURL"]];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{

            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{                    

                cell.myImageView.image = image;         

            });
        });
}
```

So after a little research my solution to this was:

```
-(void)loadAsyncImage:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:someData[indexPath.row][@"photoURL"] ];


    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            // _myTableView a property link from the interface builder
            myCell * cell = (id)[_myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.myImageView.image = myImage;


    });
});

}
```

and then in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myCellID";
    myCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self loadAsyncImage: indexPath];
}
```

To my surprise it works and is so much more cleaner...but... i dont know if this is the right way to do this. Is there a better approach to this issue? or is this ok?

Comment: It's okay, but two issues:  small one: no need to reload that cell if it isn't currently visible (it might have scrolled away).  big one: without caching the result, you'll be launching and relaunching the same request as user scroll back and forth.  Please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655360/images-downloaded-asynchronously-only-appear-in-uitableview-after-tap-or-scroll/12656334#12656334

Comment: yes i do have caching in my actually code. just couldn't bother to write out everything. I really appreciate the feedback. will look into your 1st issue.

Comment: the other minor point is that sendAsynch in NSURLConnection writes all that GCD code for you.

Comment: Yeah i just saw your solution. It's awesome! thanks so much.

Comment: @danh He's not reloading the cell if it's scrolled off screen.  UITableView's `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` returns nil for indexPaths that are not visible.

Comment: ooooh thanks David. less coding for me then