# Asynchronously download images for UITableView using NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, asynchronous

I have a TableView with customCells, when user press Start button on some cell the loading starts. There are many such cells, so I need to implement this downloading in parallel (asynchronously). 
For image downloading and updating the cell in Table view I use next code:

```
#define myAsyncQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
```

I include this method into the async queue, that I supposed should enable parallel downloading of images.
    - (void)didClickStartAtIndex:(NSInteger)cellIndex withData:

```
    (CustomTableViewCell*)data
    {
 dispatch_async(myAsyncQueue, ^{        
self.customCell = data;
        self.selectedCell = cellIndex;
        ObjectForTableCell* tmp =[self.dataDictionary objectForKey:self.names[cellIndex]];

        NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tmp.imeageURL]
                                                    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                                timeoutInterval:60.0];
        self.connectionManager = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
       }); 
    }
    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
    {
          self.urlResponse = response;

        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
        NSDictionary *dict = httpResponse.allHeaderFields;
        NSString *lengthString = [dict valueForKey:@"Content-Length"];
        NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        NSNumber *length = [formatter numberFromString:lengthString];
        self.totalBytes = length.unsignedIntegerValue;

        self.imageData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:self.totalBytes];
    }

    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
    {
           [self.imageData appendData:data];
        self.customCell.progressView.progress = ((100.0/self.urlResponse.expectedContentLength)*self.imageData.length)/100;
          float per = ((100.0/self.urlResponse.expectedContentLength)*self.imageData.length);
        self.customCell.realProgressStatus.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.f%%", per];

    }

   I tried to set this block to queue - main queue - cause its the place where image is already downloaded,

        -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
        {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.customCell.realProgressStatus.text = @"Downloaded";

            UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:self.imageData];
            self.customCell.image.image = img;
            self.customCell.tag = self.selectedCell;
    });
            [self.savedImages setObject:img forKey:self.customCell.nameOfImage.text];
            NSNumber *myNum = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:self.selectedCell];
            [self.tagsOfCells addObject:myNum];
       }
```

Without all queues(when I comment it)all works properly - but just 1 downloading at a ones. 
But when I tried to implement code with queues as a result it doesn't download anything. I understand that I did smh wrong but I can't define it.

Thanks a lot for any help in advance.

Comment: [just try this lib](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Comment: @Fahim, thank you for an advice , I am learning, and wanted to implement it by myself, without any third party library, well at least try to do it by myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your looking out for starting it form basics I guess you should start with [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/downloadTaskWithURL:) as [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/) most of implementation had been deprecated and won't be available after iOS 9. For complete reference [URL Session Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i)  and [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial)

Coming back to your question you should do something similar to this took it from tutorial

```
// 1
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *getImageTask =
[session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]

    completionHandler:^(NSURL *location,
                        NSURLResponse *response,
                        NSError *error) {
        // 2
        UIImage *downloadedImage =
          [UIImage imageWithData:
              [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location]];
      //3
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // do stuff with image
        _imageWithBlock.image = downloadedImage;
      });
}];

// 4
[getImageTask resume];
```

But my personal recommendation is go for [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) which is best for iOS networking and widely used/tested in iOS app world.

For image download using AFNetworking

```
[_imageView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i.imgur.com/fVhhR.png"]]
                      placeholderImage:nil
                               success:^(NSURLRequest *request , NSHTTPURLResponse *response , UIImage *image ){
                                   NSLog(@"Loaded successfully: %d", [response statusCode]);
                               }
                               failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
                                   NSLog(@"failed loading: %@", error);
                               }
    ];
```

EDIT : Async downloading using concurrency

```
// get main dispact queue
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
// adding downloading task in queue using block
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
  NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
  UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
  // after download compeletes geting main queue again as there can a possible crash if we assign directly
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    _imageWithBlock.image = image;
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you vey much, yes I know that NSURLConnection is deprecated , I will move to NSURLSession, but currently I need to solve this issue in current project

Comment: then this must be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655360/images-downloaded-asynchronously-only-appear-in-uitableview-after-tap-or-scroll

Comment: Thank you very much for help)).

Answer (score 2):

Use this sample code from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394) to solve your problem of lazy loading.